# Can't make HTML5 Audio Tag to work on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, audio

I have a web app that uses the HTML5 `<audio>` tag and for some reason, while it works fine on Windows and Mac PCs, it doesn't work on iOS and Android.
Here's a relevant snippet of my code:

Javascript:

```
var audioElement = document.querySelector('#audioplayer');
var source = document.querySelector('#mp3');
source.src = tokObject._url;
audioElement.load();
audioElement.play();
```

HTML:

```
<center>
    <audio id="audioplayer" style="width:480px;">
        <source id="mp3" src="random-placeholder" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>
</center>
```

Comment: what browser you tested the code with ? i it opera it will not work

Comment: Chrome and Safari on iOS and Android

Answer (score 3):

You normally can't autoplay audio or video files on mobile devices, this is often a restriction by the OSes such as Android and iOS to stop sites from downloading huge media files and autoplaying them.

If such code is called from within a click or touch handler, it will probably work, but not the way you are currently doing it.

Also, the `<center>` element has been deprecated and you shouldn't use it anymore.

Comment: The code is being called from a click, is there a way to bypass this restriction?

Comment: No, there is no way to bypass this restriction, that's the point of it. But, since the code is being called on a click event I am surprised that it isn't working. Perhaps try removing the .load() and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks Ian, I'll check it out soon to see if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I did this instead and it worked for me. While I am not playing an MP3 I am getting a voice to prompt the user through a loop.

```
function speak(text) {
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
msg.voice = voices[2];
msg.voiceURI = 'native';
msg.volume = 1;
msg.rate = 1;
msg.pitch = 1;
msg.text = text;
msg.lang = 'en-US';

speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

// insert this bottom bit to call the function and it will read in the mobiles native voice what you type in ie....rest   works on android have not tried iphone.

speak('rest');

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried it doing this way :

```
var aud=new Audio(file.mp3);
aud.play();
```