# html audio tag is not auto playing the audio

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, text-to-speech, ibm-cloud

Here follows the code snippet am using where TextToSpeech is a servlet which returns audio stream (via ServletOutputStream).

```
<audio autoplay controls>
    <source src="/TextToSpeech?input=Welcome" type="audio/wav" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element
</audio>
```

But Chrome browser is NOT auto-playing the audio. Can any one help me please?

P.S: I did test the audio stream by saving it to a file and it played well. So no issue with audio that returned from the server.

Comment: That question will need some more info, like the output of the "network" panel in Chrome. Are you sure the headers for the stream are set correctly ? Does it work when you call `audio.play()` ?

Comment: It worked if I download the audio stream as a file and played it.
I didn't try using audio.play(). will that make any difference?

Comment: ok. I noticed one thing. Looks like its getting auto-played in Chrome browser (in desktop) but not in Chrome (in mobile).
Any ideas?

Comment: both desktop and mobile chrome versions are same though.

Comment: After further browsing...I understood that we can't auto-play in a mobile device :-( insane
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515237/cant-make-html5-audio-tag-to-work-on-mobile-browsers

Answer (score 0):

On mobile the audio autoplay function is usually disabled in order to avoid data traffic usage without explicit action from the user.

You could workaround that using javascript, when the page is loaded (i.e. jQuery.onready() ) you can start playing the audio file with something like that:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audioId");
audio.autoplay = true;
audio.load();
```