# Running audio works on desktop, but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to run audio. I try to run it without displaying any player. Here is what I did to play it in simple javascript way;

```
new Audio('http://www.example.org/calbeni.mp3').play();
```

Works quite nicely. However, on mobile, it doesn't work (without any errors).
What is the correct way to make it work on mobile?

Comment: iOS doesn't allow audio to start automatically...

Comment: Thanks for your input. That's not starting automatically. It works onclick.

Comment: You should consider updating your post with more details for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there are issues with running audio files automatically in the browser.

See this SO post: [Can't make HTML5 Audio Tag to work on mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515237/cant-make-html5-audio-tag-to-work-on-mobile-browsers)